# Как проверить возможность преобразования типов? C++

Tags: c++, преобразование-типов

Допустим есть функция, которая в зависимости от возможности преобразовать аргумент к тому или иному типу возвращает разное значение. Как проверить возможность преобразовать тип? Если возможно, то вернуть значение 1, если нет, то значение 2? Абстрактный код:

```
template<typename T>
Base my_cast(T mclass) {

    if (convertable_to_Base)
        return { mclass };
    else
        return Base::NULL;

}
```

Comment: Параметр передаётся по значению - плохо.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy как я написал, это абстрактный код, который создан, чтобы пользователи сообщества имели возможность лучше понять задачу. Вы еще придеритесь, что вместо if можно тернарный оператор использовать, чтобы сократить код аж на 3 строчки

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy dynamic_cast позволяет же приводить только ссылки и указатели, разве не так?

Comment: @ComeInRage Причем только для экземпляров полиморфных классов.

Comment: `convertable_to_Base` намекает на наследование. Преобразование унаследованного типа к базовому с копированием - это срезка. Срезка - зло. Я не придираюсь, указываю на плохой дизайн. Вы задачу решите, а результату не будете рады.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я не имел ввиду наследование. convertable_to_base - это абстрактное условие. Я не знаю, как проверить возможность преобразования, поэтому вместо него поставил абстрактное convertable_to_base. У меня даже нет конкретной задачи и этот код я составил лишь с целью более подробного изложения своей мысли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способов преобразования много разных. [Почти столько же, сколько видов инициализации...](https://i.imgur.com/GI53BSo.gif)

Для самых распространенных из них в стандартной библиотеке есть trait-ы, например:

- [`std::is_convertible_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) - преобразование возможно без каста,
- [`std::is_constructible_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) - преобразование возможно при создании переменной: `тип переменная(выражение);`.

Примеры использования см. в конце ответа.

Первое гарантирует (обычно?), что вообще любое преобразование сработает, в т. ч. неявное. По идее, первое гарантирует второе.

Второе гарантирует, например, что `static_cast` сработает, но не гарантирует что сработает неявное преобразование.

Даже если они оба вернули `false`, какой-нибудь `static_cast` все равно может сработать.

Если вам не подходят стандартные trait-ы (потому что вы проверяете более редкий способ преобразования), то вы можете написать свой подобный trait с помощью SFINAE.

В C++20 вы также можете использовать `requires`. Он удобен тем, что не нужно помнить, какой trait проверяет какой синтаксис. Вы просто втыкаете интересующий вас синтаксис в `requires`, см. пример в конце.

Независимо от выбранного способа проверки, нужно использовать `if constexpr` вместо `if`. Обычный `if` проверяет обе ветки на валидность, даже если одна из них никогда не будет выполнена, поэтому если преобразование для какого-то типа невозможно, вы получили бы ошибку компиляции независимо от того, что вы поставили в условие.

Пример раз:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To my_cast(From value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<To, From &>)
        return To(value); 
    else
        return {};
}
```

Или, что более правильно:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To my_cast(From &&value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<To, From>)
        return To(std::forward<From>(value)); 
    else
        return {};
}
```

Обычно этого достаточно.

Однако `is_constructible` - это более жесткое требование, чем возможность сделать сишный каст `To(value)`. Например,

```
enum class E {e = 42};
std::cout << my_cast<int>(E::e) << '\n';
```

выводит `0`, хотя такой каст возможен.

Если вас это не устраивает, то тут очень удобен `requires`:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To my_cast(From &&value)
{
    if constexpr (requires{To(std::forward<From>(value))})
        return To(std::forward<From>(value)); 
    else
        return {};
}
```

Он позволяет проверить на валидность именно тот преобразование, которое вы собираетесь сделать.

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ, который решает мою проблему. Больше всего помогла заметка о том, что нужно использовать constexpr, я об этом не знал) Однако есть сопутствующий вопрос. Почему правильнее использовать && и std::forward, а не обычную передачу типа по ссылке?

Comment: @ComeInRage *"обычную передачу типа по ссылке"* Т.е. по константной ссылке?

Comment: Именно так. Чем отличается от этого std::forward?

Comment: @ComeInRage Предположим у вас есть `std::string foo() {return ...;}` и вы делаете `my_cast<std::optional<std::string>>(foo())` (или просто `my_cast<std::string>(foo())`). С константной ссылкой здесь будет копирование, а с `std::forward` - перемещение. Это называется "perfect forwarding".